# R with gsub() instead ' of \'

Tags: r, gsub

I want let a string like "ab'" become "ab\'"

I have tried following code

```
aa="ab'"
aa<-gsub("'","\\'",aa)
```

show  ab'

```
aa="ab'"
aa<-gsub("'","\\\'",aa)
```

show  ab'

```
aa="ab'"
aa<-gsub("'","\\\\'",aa)
```

show  ab\\'

I don't know how to fixed it 
please give me some suggest

Comment: Use `cat` to see actual output , `cat(sub("'", "\\\\", aa))`

Comment: @r2evans This is to distinguish from control characters.  There is similar behavior with quotes sometimes.

Comment: @r2evans `cat` is exactly the way to force seeing the difference

Comment: Apparently I no longer understand how backslashes work in R.

Comment: thanks Ronak Shan. I use cat to see the result. and it can work successfully

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the following code:

```
aa <- "ab'"
aa <- gsub("'", "\\\\'", aa)
```

In fact you are replacing a single quote with a single literal backslash.  The output you see `ab\\'` I believe just shows an extra backslash to let you know that it is not an escape character.

Consider the following extension of your code:

```
gsub("\\\\", "A", gsub("'","\\\\'",aa))
[1] "abA'"
```

We can clearly see that there is only a single `A` in the replacement, implying that there was only a single backslash to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Even though on the terminal, you sometimes see "\\" it is actually just "\".

Print the result using writeLines() to see the actual string:

```
> original_string = "ab'"
> new_string = gsub("'","\\\\",original_string)
> writeLines(new_string)
ab\
```

Bonus funny: https://xkcd.com/1638/